# Blazor server-side Input Field: Combine Onchange and Bind

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a page with loads of input fields. They are fed their initial values from a model that is fetched from a SQL server.

Every time the user changes a value in one of the input fields I want to send the new value to the SQL server.

My first idea was to use the onchange event to trigger the sql update and the @bind event to update the model.
As it turned out, Onchange and blazors' @bind do not work together, since @bind already implements an onchange eventhandler.

My current solution is to set the @bind to the oninput event. Here's the code

```
<input @onchange="@(e => ValueChanged(e, "someid"))" @bind-value="@this.model.someValue" @bind-value:event="oninput" class="form-control form-control-sm border rounded" />

private void ValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e, string id)
{
    // Update the sql server
}
```

This works to get around the issue. But it creates a lot of traffic. For every letter the user enters in the input field, a message is send to the server instead of one message once he is finished.

**Is there a better way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

For single-line string inputs, I usually use the Keyup event to check for Enter.  (I might also add a submit button as well just in case the user tabs out or clicks out without hitting enter):

```
<input @onkeyup="ValueChanged" @bind="SomeText" />

@code {
     string SomeText;
     public async Task ValueChanged(KeyboardEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.Code == "Enter")
        {
             // Do SQL stuff with SomeText
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: And how would I recognize a change when the user does not hit enter and instead just clicks inside another field?

Comment: *"I might also add a submit button as well just in case the user tabs out or clicks out without hitting enter."*  If you don't want to do that, then I recommend following @enet's advice.